# The first thing I can see in this picture ‘are’ 2 people

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, inversion, complements

> The first thing I can see in this picture **are** 2 people

I happened to see this sentence, and it says using 'is' instead of 'are' is wrong.

As I looked up some grammar stuff, you can invert the complement if it is not a noun but an adjective or an adverb.
Also the subject “the first thing” does not seem to be a sort of unit such as *2 inches* as in

> “2 inches **is** not that long.”

So I would like to ask why and how the verb should be 'are', not 'is'.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be overthinking this. What is the subject of the following sentence? What is the verb?

- The first **thing** I can see in this picture **are** 2 people.

(Hint: I made them bold.) With a singular subject you need a singular verb. Thus, **is** should be used instead of **are**.

Answer (score 0):

I would opine that many native speakers would say

> In this picture I can see two people.

There is no need to start with a list, *The first thing...* especially if the photo is detailed, but the OP wants to know if using the plural verb in this instance is grammatical or not

> The first thing [that] I can see {in this picture}  *are* 2 people

If we take away the ***th***-words (*that*, *this*, *there*) we are left with

> WRONG: The first thing I can see ***are*** two people

Although it doesn't sound wrong because the verb agrees with the predicate plural noun, *two people*; it disagrees with the subject of the sentence which is "The first thing". In fact, it follows the standard Subject Verb Object ([SVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object))  order

> CORRECT: The first thing I can see ***is*** two people

The plural "two people" after the singular verb makes it sound a bit strange even though "two people" is not the subject of the verb. But verbs MUST agree with their subject.

1. • *“The first thing”* is a noun phrase which is the **subject**
   • *“[that] I can see”* **is a reduced relative clause**

(Since the relative clause has a subject (I) already, the relative word, *that*, is unnecessary and may be omitted.)

2. • *“in this picture”* is a [prepositional phrase](https://www.thoughtco.com/prepositional-phrase-1691663), and it is the complement of the verb "see". The verb *“be”* is the [copula](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copular_verb) or linking verb.